# How to make Pandas.DataFrame.append() efficient?

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

I am trying to appending records to a DataFrame object. So the DataFrame objects grows bigger and bigger, and eventually the number of records reaches 2 millions.

The code I've used is:

```
for item in item_list:
    if some_condition:
        fitered_df = filtered_df.append(pd.Series([my_record]), ignore_index=True)
```

I've noticed that the program slows down as the `filtered_df` grows bigger. Thanks to @Goyo's answer that I know it is because the `append()` function reallocates memory for `filtered_df` every time.

Is there a better way to achieve the goal, or there is a more efficient way to append records to DataFrame object?

PS：I have no idea how many records will be appended, so I cannot pre-allocate memory for the DataFrame object.

Comment: Many better ways. Please describe an specific problem and post a [mcve] that we can actually run.

Answer (score 0):

No, constructing a big DataFrame by appending records one at a time is not efficient. Avoid it.

Comment: What should be used instead?

Comment: @Cleb Well, that's too broad. It depends on a lot of things.

Comment: Why is it not efficient?

Comment: @ChangeMyName Allocating or reallocating memory as the object grows is worse than allocating it at once.

Comment: @goyo Thanks. But I have no idea how many records will be appended, so is there an alternative way to allocate the memory at the beginning?